# Why can't a variable initialized in an `if` condition be used in the if's block?

Tags: ruby

So it is common to initialize a variable in an `if` condition, and then use that variable inside the if's block.

```
if a = foo()
   puts a
end
```

However when I initialize a variable and use it in the same if's block, that var will not be considered initialized at that time. For example:

```
def good?(item)
  puts "item is #{item.inspect}"
  true
end

if b = 52 && good?(b)
  puts "b is #{b.inspect}"
end
```

Run the above and the result would be

```
item is nil
b is true
```

Why is this the case? What kind of keyword is related to this Ruby behavior that I search for and study about it?

Comment: @DevonParsons yep it is above the if statement

Comment: It's considered bad practice to initialize or assign to a variable in the conditional test. It's difficult to see and is easily misunderstood when debugging. It's often done in old-school Perl but even there it's discouraged for the same reasons these days.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The precedence of `&&` is higher than `=`, so

```
if b = 52 && good?(b)
```

is equivalent to:

```
if b = (52 && good?(b))
```

Reference: [Operator Precedence](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/doc/syntax/precedence_rdoc.html).

Answer (score 8):

You're assigning to `b` the result of `52 && good?(b)`. `b` is still `nil` when it is passed to `good?`.

Parenthesis are the key.

```
def good?(item)
  puts "item is #{item.inspect}"
  true
end

if (b = 52) && good?(b)
  puts "b is #{b.inspect}"
end
```

Result:

```
item is 52
b is 52
```

Comment: Using `and` instead of `&&` is an alternative way since it has a lower precedence than `=`. [Parentheses are the preferred way though](https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide#safe-assignment-in-condition).